# Best Strategy for a Modular App in Django regarding the Templates

Tags: django

I'm working in a Django project and in the development process I created a App that I believe could be useful in other projects. I think I have develope a fairly modular app in all but one aspect. And this is the object of this question: template.

In my case, one of my pages generate a table, and trying to keep as clean as possible, I did not add any CSS, div, or anything. Just the clean HTML. Now, how would I use this app in other projects making this table look presentable? You know, with the usual CSS styles and even JS (for table reordering for example). The solution that I thought was to add {% blocks %} all over the place in the original app code, but that not seem appropriate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you have code in template for generating a table and you want that to be used in other projects?

Comment: Well... Yes. But, by the tone of your question, seems something that I should not do. :) My hope was to make a totally pluggable app regarding it's template.

Comment: @Rodrogo: there's no way you can "make your app totally pluggable regarding it's template", because there's no way for you to know how some project's base templates will be structured, what blocks will be defined etc. The best thing you can do is to provide the simplest possible working templates and good documention of the view's contexts (including what may come from context processors) so that your app's user can override them without too much pain.

Comment: I understand that now. But I just feel that is extremely wasteful to have to rewrite the template, even if starting from the simplest template already made. I would like very much just write something along the lines of: "Django, get that table generated by the template inside the App and apply this style." :)

Comment: Rajeev's suggestion to use an include template is about as far as you can go here, but from experience your app's user will rewrite the template anyway, because they have specific layouts, specific css, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrt/ reusable apps, the usual pattern is to deliver minimal working templates with the application (in appname/templates/appname/), and override them on a per-project basis in the project's template dir. Templates are really project-specific and are one of the "integration" layer so there's no way you can provide a one-size-fits-all template.

Answer (score 2):

To create a pluggable app as you said in your comment,you can create a template directory inside your app.for example `app/templates` other than the one in your template_dir setting.

In the template use extends to inherit a base html file that may vary from site to site.

In your template that renders the table

`table.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% include "cleantable.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

```
<html>
project specific CSS
project specific JS
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

So in effect your project structure will be as follows

```
project
  |
  |---pluggable
  |      |
  |      |--templates
  |      |     |
  |      |     |---cleantable.html
  |      |     |
  |      |     |---table.html
  |      |     
  |      |--views.py <renders pluggable templates>
  |  
  |---templates<site specific templates>
  |    |
  |    |---base.html<site specific design>
  |
  |---<other apps>
```